# Setup quietmodem android library for desktop java application

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to use the Quiet modem [library](https://github.com/quiet/org.quietmodem.Quiet) on a desktop java application using Gradle.

I've tried to build the library using "./gradlew build", but get the error `Could not determine java version from '11.0.19'.`

Should I be using the android library on desktop or is it better to write java bindings to the C library? Or how could I modify the gradle to get it working?